# Marshaling fixed-size array of reference type as linear buffer in memory?

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, low-level

I'll try to sum up my initial problem before comes to the actual question of this topic just for a better understanding. If you dont want to read, ignore the summing up section and go straight for the second section when I actually explain the problem.

## **Suming up the problem**

I'm emulating a MMORPG server of a game that already exists (just for study, I already know publishing that in any way is illegal) and I'm facing a lot of trouble when "translating" the raw packets buffer to some structure in code that I can use to avoid having to reference the data in the packets by its offsets in the buffer.

I have some background in reversing and C++. This problem is easily solved in C++ by doing the follow (consider 'packetBuffer' as a 'char*').

```
MyStructureType* packet = (MyStructureType*)&packetBuffer[0];
```

The problem starts in the fact that C# offer very much less freedom with user memory management. I can still use pointers, but there are a lot of things I can't do (eg. consider a struct X I use to represent the packet Y, if X have the need to declare a fixed-size array of another structure, even if all the types involved are blittable, I'm in trouble: C# just doesn't allow this). So the solution I took is make these packet structures as classes, format the layout of them (using attributes as StructLayout and MarshalAs) and then use the methods Marshal.PtrToStructure and Marshal.StructureToPtr to convert the raw buffer (byte[]) in some high-level representation and vice-versa. Now we come to my actual problem.

## **The Actual Question**

Well, as stated above, I have POD classes that I use as a higher-level representation of packets data (byte[]). Imagine the packet represents a complex structure which have some nested custom structures. It's all fine until the point I have to declare a fixed size array, represented by a "marshalable" class. Consider I declare an array with 3 elements of the class X inside the class Y, I will end up with 3 references (pointers) to the actual data of X, not the 3 elements "hard-coded" in the buffer of Y. Some code to clarify bellow.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class X
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class Y
{
    X _x1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    X[] _x2;
}
```

Instantiating Y, I will end up with an object which have 20 bytes instead of 32 (8 bytes for _x1 + 12 bytes for 3 pointers (4 bytes each) for each data for the three elements of_x2).

So, finally the question: how can I make _x2 be hard-coded in Y instead of storing the pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to embed the memory of one type into another in C# is for the member type to be a struct.

Comment: Not exatly. As I show in the topic, the problem comes up when you start dealing with arrays. '_x1' in my example is embeded in instances of Y!

Comment: The only thing contained in _x1 is a pointer to an X.  Put an int field right before it and compare the addresses of the int field before _x1 and one of the ints in the X.

Comment: No dude, it is not. _x1 have 8 bytes and is embeded in any instance of Y! Give it a try and run the code I wrote in the topic!

Comment: When I try to take the address of y._x1.i1 after newing up a Y I get a null reference exception.  How is that possible unless it's a reference that's stored in _x1?  I am telling you, with ten years of experience writing in bytecode, that _x1 is 8 bytes because you are running in 64 bit mode, not because two ints are embedded in Y.

Comment: Hmmm.
If _x1 is 8 bytes because my OS on 64 bit mode, why _x2 have 12 bytes? The only reason I came up is that 12 bytes is 3 pointers * 4 bytes for each pointer.

Comment: @hoodaticus PS.: I'm getting the size of the objects using Marshal.SizeOf(). Do you think this may be leading to some wrong value?

Comment: Not sure, but I guarantee  you that any field of any structure or class that is of a type that does not inherit System.ValueType will contain a managed reference.  Only structs inherit System.ValueType.  You can verify this by taking a full memory dump, loading up WinDBG with sosex extension, and running the do (dump object) command on the address of one of your Y objects.  You can use dumpheap -type Namespace.Y to get a list of all the Y's in the process.

Comment: As for sizeof and Marshal.SizeOf, you should be aware that even an empty object in .NET is 12 bytes.  That is the smallest grain the allocator works with.

Comment: Dude, with all the respect, I **strongly** think you are confusing in that. I ran a test here. Instantiated Y, setted different values for all the integer fields at X (_x1 and _x2 in Y) and then dumped the respective byte array in file as a .bin using the Marshal.StructureToPtr method. And the result in the file.bin is exataly what I said: 8 bytes with the values of _x1 and 3 pointers of each element of _x2. Make test I told and see with your own eyes. I think it's possible that me and you are both right. CLR can alloc the data as you said but when the Marshal comes to play he works as I said.

Comment: Have you tried my test yet?  New up a Y without initializing _x1, then do this: fixed (int* y = y._x1.i1).  You will get a null reference exception.  The Marshal class does all sorts of violence including making copies before marshalling.  It does not represent your in-memory layout, which I know is what you want because you are like me.

Comment: You probably get null for _x1 because _x1 is a reference type, and as such don't have a zero-initialization. If you initialize _x1 and _x2 you will end up with what I said.

Comment: For all the reference types inside a custom type you have to explicit call new() in order to instantiate the object. And even doing this you can't take address of a managed type (X is a reference type). The solution using Marshal is exatly for this case: it somehow "converts" the managed world to unmanaged and vice-versa.

Comment: I added an int field to the top of Y (before _x1).  Then I allocated a Y, then allocated a 5000 byte array (referred only by a local variable), then allocated an X and assigned it to y._x1.  These are their memory addresses: Y: 39769488
Y._x1.i1: 39774536.  So either the size of a single instance of Y is over 5,000 bytes or I'm right.

Comment: Yes @hoodaticus. As I said, the CLR allocates _x1 and _x2 in the managed heap; I agree with you in this point. All I'm trying to say is that you can Marshal the classes in the same way you can Marshal a struct. Again: I know they will not end up in a linear address of RAM, but the attributes StructLayout and MarshalAs give instructions in the generated IL of the respective classes on how to organize these data in a layout described by the attributes I told, even if they are in different locations in memory at runtime; Marshal will create another object in memory with the desired layout.

Comment: The point is that you don't need to use Marshal at all with blittable types.  You can spew raw memory straight into a stream, such as to a graphics or network interface.  This means speed.  Use structs.  It stinks that you can't hide their construction, but perhaps you can punish them for using default instances >:D

Comment: @hoodaticus I can't do this. As I said, some of my structs have arrays of another structs, and is impossible in c# to declare an fixed array of anything but primitive types. Therefore, if I can't "spew" raw memory into the stream, I have to appel to Marshal at this point; and if I have to use Marshal to deal with the arrays, better make then classes because they are very much scalable than structs.

Comment: my second answer with the union allows you to use array syntax in your goal type provided you can compute the size of the structure at compile time.

Comment: Yeah, I will try it in a moment. But even if that works I have the problem of the very poor scalability using structs and unsafe code in C#. For example: to deal with Strings in a "unsafe manner" I have to declare a fixed array of sbyte and create a helper method to get the String with a specific Encoding, make it for EVERY string in all the packet structures is hell! The Marshal do all this job for me automatically. Do you think it is viable to modify the Roslyn to accomplish that?

Comment: If the strings are using UTF-16 then you have no need for encoding >:D  If it's UTF8 though then you win.

Comment: Anyway, very nice time talking to you^^ Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

You are right that there is a dumb restriction on using primitives in fixed size arrays.  I have no idea why they don't just test for blittability.

Anyway, if you know you have 3 Foos in your fixed-size array, why don't you just create a wrapper struct that contains Foo1, Foo2, and Foo3 and make it a member of your struct?

BTW I advise against using classes for this kind of work.  Use structs - it's what they're there for.  Classes have two machine words of extra metadata in front.

```
struct Root
{
     //fixed Leaf[] Leaves[3]; -- not allowed by C#
     Leaf3 Leaves;  //this is okay though, for some reason
}

struct Leaf
{
     int x1;
     int x2;
}

struct Leaf3
{
     Leaf Leaf1;
     Leaf Leaf2;
     Leaf Leaf3;
}
```

Comment: Because in the project I will have tons of structures, some of them very big in data. If the point here is just to avoid reference the packet data by its offsets in the buffer your solution is not the most viable :(

And yeah, I can't realize the "why" of this restiction :/

Comment: The alternative is to pointer cast a fixed-size array of byte, sadly.

Comment: I will not give up :P Until I find some solution to that I don't breath hehe. Thanks anyway for the advance!

Comment: I am posting an alternate answer then, maybe you'll dislike it equally XD.

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by using a [struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx). Then I ask why _x2 can't be a struct as well. Something like this:

```
struct XArray
{
   X _x1;
   X _x2;
   X _x3;
}
```

In C# you won't be able to use an indexer on the struct but you can still access the elements as needed.

Comment: I can't use struct because I have to hide any default instantiation of these types. In these complex types I have to do some critical-initialization in the constructor, such as initialize the arrays. Once I can't hide all the default constructors of a struct, I switched for classes which I can make the default constructor private and I have the guarantee that no one will create an instance of the type without calling my custom constructor. And for your example: try to imagine that I have to use the layout I wrote in the topic, please.

Comment: Of course I could do what you told, but in the project I have tons of different structures which some of them are pretty big. Once the idea here is to avoid keep referencing the data by its offset in the buffer, I can't do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a union.  This is basically Structure Hack for C#, allowing you to access your Leafs by taking a Leaf* to &Leaf and then accessing it with array or pointer syntax as you please.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct Root
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    Leaf Leaf;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    fixed byte packing[24]; //reserves size of three Leafs.
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
unsafe struct Leaf
{
    int X1;
    int X2;
}
```